# How to recursively declare this type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

What I want to declare is a type that can hold a string, or a function that returns a string, or a function that returns a function that returns a string, and so forth.

Basically something like this, but recursively and possibly without the arbitrary limitation of 5 functions I have now.

```js
type NestedStringProvider =
string |
(() => string) |
(() => () => string) |
(() => () => () => string) |
(() => () => () => () => string) |
(() => () => () => () => () => string);
```

So that I could do:

```js
let s: NestedStringProvider;
s = "foobar"; // ok
s = function () { return () => "string" }; // ok
s = 1; // error
```

I'm using TypeScript 3.1.6. I would be ready to upgrade if that helps with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply refer to your type recursively:

```
type NestedStringProvider =
    | string
    | (() => NestedStringProvider);
```

[Checkout a playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDKwBOBLAdgcwAUMB7ANy2QgygF4AoKRqAHykW3wadYAoeBKWgD5YCJGky5CJcpQz8A3HToBjYjkRQAZsWIAuUYhToO0shSq0oAcgAWEADYPiAGigB3YhgfJrStRrAUABGAIYYBnBGEqZE5nJWAsI29k6uHl4+fqrqmmEAXpFixpL4cbKWNFBJNCI1InaOzm6e3r4KQA)